# How to parse through FB Graph API friends list array for specific value, ID?

Tags: arrays, facebook-graph-api, loops

I successfully loaded the friends array containing more arrays into a variable. But how do I iterate through it to take only the id's out?

I used:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends/');
```

It returns a multidimensional array like so:

```
array(1) { ["name"] => "Username" ["id"] => "User ID #"}

array(2) { ["name"] => "Username" ["id"] => "User ID #"} 

...and so on...
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of Graph API almost always contain `data` property which is contain all the response data, to get only the friends ids you can look over it in such way:

```
// If all you need is users ids, specify it in fields url argument
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends/?fields=id');
$data = $friends['response'];
$friendsIds = array();
for ($data as $user){
  $friendsIds[] = $user['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$yourIdArr = array();
foreach($yourFriendArray as $key => $val) {
 if("id" == $key) {
    array_push($yourIdArr, $val);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hmm just tried it and I get an empty Array when I use print_r...any other suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are your doing your foreach with `$friends` (result from `$facebook->api('/me/friends/')` ) ? Isn't there a `['data']` index on it where all the sub-arrays are stored ?

Comment: Your sample is wrong! `$val` is really an array which contain `id` key, `$key` in this case is a numeric index...